# Update entry title for all sites

Tags: craft3, entries, localization, modules

I'm working on a Craft project that has 3 sites. The content for one section is pulled from an API using a console script which runs every 5 minutes.

This has been working fine but I've discovered a bug that the title's aren't being updated across all sites as they are translatable.

This is my current code.

```
$entry->title = $data->name;
$entry->setFieldValues([
    'body' => $data->text,
    'relatedArticles' => array_map(function($id){
        return [
            'relatedId' => $id,
        ];
    }, $data->related),
    'categories' => array_map(function($cat) {
        return (isset($this->categories[$cat])) ? (int) $this->categories[$cat] : false;
    }, $data->categories),
]);
$success = Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
```

All other fields are not translatable so they work fine, Is there a way to propagate the title across all sites or do I need to loop through all the sites to update the entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on the latest 3.5.x release, then my guess is you need to set the "Title Translation Method" setting for whatever Entry Type you're saving to to "Translate for each site".

[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware of this new feature! Thank you, this fixed the issue for me.